# How to randomly generate layout on a 2D Array?

Tags: algorithm, layout, knapsack-problem

I have a 2D array of a predetermined size and a list of numbered rectangles to fit into that space.  Each of these rectangles has a known, fixed height and width.  The 2D array is guaranteed to be large enough to fit all of the rectangles comfortably.

I need to randomly place each of these rectangles into the array so that none overlap and all are placed.  They can be placed in any orientation.  Imagine placing your ships in a game of battleship, just with many more varied ship sizes and a much larger grid.

The finished array should look something like this: (0 represents an empty space, a non-zero number represents a rectangle number)

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 **1 1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **4 4 4** 0
0 **1 1** 0 **2 2 2 2 2** 0 0 0 **4 4 4** 0
0 **1 1** 0 **2 2 2 2 2** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 **2 2 2 2 2** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 **2 2 2 2 2** 0 **5 5** 0 0 0 0
0 **3 3 3 3 3** 0 0 0 0 **5 5** 0 0 0 0
0 **3 3 3 3 3** 0 **7 7 7 5 5 6 6** 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **7 7 7 5 5 6 6** 0 0

One approach I've considered is for each rectangle, select a random placement and orientation, attempt to place it in the matrix.  If a collision with a previously placed block is detected, try again.  This would probably be the simplest to implement but it doesn't seem very efficient and it doesn't terminate in a clearly deterministic way (a rectangle near the end of the list could keep colliding with previously generated blocks for quite a while).

Is there a better way to go about this that wouldn't be so problematic for placing the later rectangles?

Comment: If the random method works with letters, it should work with rectangles too: http://openprocessing.org/sketch/1811

Comment: @biziclop Looks like they have a 50 attempt "timeout" of sorts to keep the algorithm from going on forever when out of room.  I guess failing gracefully would be a safe enough approach.

Comment: What is the purpose of the algo? To lay out boxes which are pleasant to look at?

Comment: @biziclop It's meant to create a child in the first generation for a genetic algorithm.  The GA will then optimize the layout based on other parameters.

Comment: I would sort the boxes by size, then start packing the biggest box at a corner, and try to stick the next one to an already placed one. Unfortunately it wouldn't be too random :)

Comment: @biziclop the Randomness in much more crucial to the algorithm's success than fitting everything in unfortunately.

Comment: Another idea: put N 1x1 rectangles to the plane, and start growing them, in each step choose a random side wich has free pixel next to it and occupy it.

Comment: Q:1)are you seeking for maximum coverage ? 2)do you have any priority between rectangles, I mean biggest first ? 3) what about situation when there is no enough space left to feet next rectangle ?

Comment: @Ruslan I have very few parameters.  I'm seeking fairly uniform but random placement over all.  The size of the array is mathematically guaranteed to have enough area available.  I don't know if it is possible to create an arrangement that would prevent enough continuous space being available, but it is improbable enough to be ignored.

Comment: So basically you are looking for algorithm to place all rectangles on a matrix in some random way. You should consider possible unlucky situation when distance between already placed rectangles is smaller than remaining rectangle and for this case it's very hard to find strong mathematical guarantee.

Comment: @Ruslan Fortunately I only have to run this once in the setup portion of my algorithm.  If that unlucky situation happens, I can start over and try again with little cost.  If it keeps happening, the parameters for the algorithm need to be adjusted (i.e. larger matrix)

Comment: @Thorsten Not sure that works.  If I have 2 rectangles that are 8x8 and my matrix is 16x16, placing one of the rectangles in the center of the matrix would prevent the other from fitting anywhere.  I'm using an area multiplier of 25 to limit this possibility.  Plus that multiplier has other benefits for my later algorithms

Comment: You are right, I will adjust my answer.(Oops, comments could not be edited... :-?)

Answer (score 1):

Following approach:

- <strike>Find out what your minimum dimension is. Calculate a size which is smaller than this
  dimension, but fits multiple times in your box.
  For example: Minimum size 7 cm/inch whatever, Box is 120 cm/inch. Choose 120/20 = 6 cm/inch. I hope that your problem is small enough because you will store all possible
  coordinates in a list. In this case we have 20x20 = 400 coordinates.</strike>
- To guarantee that blocking the entire area is impossible, choose your matrix that the smallest dimension (x,y) is greater or equal than the <strike>double</strike> quadruple of the maximum dimension of your rectangle (e.g. max length of rect = 8, both x and y must have at least 32) and that the entire area of your matrix has at least an area which is twice as large as all inserted elements.
- Selection of placing: Use a random number generator to randomly select a coordinate. Place the rectangle on the given coordinate and also select a random orientation. Try to set the rectangle into the box, if it does not fit first, rotate it. If it still not fits, try the next coordinate.
- If it finally fits, remove all coordinates which are overlapped by your rectangle from the list. So you are only selecting valid coordinates for other rectangles.
- Randomization: DO NOT USE linear congruential generators (which are unfortunately for your task standard for most programming languages). They have bad multidimensional characteristics. Use either secure random, hardware generators or known good ones e.g. MersenneTwister.

Comment: The author of the question insists on good randomization, not efficient tiling. If "The 2D array is guaranteed to be large enough to fit all of the rectangles comfortably.", my algorithm *will* stop and it will avoid the long pauses nearly at the end of the original approach. Your approach has a severe problem with randomization because you are already cutting the left area, therefore the new pieces have different area size and therefore different probability.

Comment: @ThorstenS. Why do you insist on starting with the smallest dimension ? Especially if The 2D array is guaranteed to be large enough to fit all of the rectangles comfortably.

Comment: When I edited my answer, some properties of the question were not obvious to me. I will adjust that

Answer (score 1):

IMO problem degrades to question - "Do we have enough space to fit next rectangle and how to find this place in efficient way ?"
So:

1. Initial condition - we have 1 rectangle available (initial matrix) in a "list of available rectangles", basically we have to store only height and weight of free rectangle and left top position on initial matrix
2. Choose random rectangle to add = "toAdd", remove it from "list to add rectangles"
3. Randomly choose free available rectangle which equal or bigger than "toAdd" = "available", remove it from "list of available rectangles", if there is no available rectangles go to step 2
4. Choose random place on "available" to add "toAdd" rectangle on it
5. Cut "available" rectangle to substract "toAdd". Different cutting strategy could apply here, but at the end you could receive maximum 4 new available rectangles
6. Add new available rectangles to "list of available rectangles"
7. go to step 2

Algorithm is not optimal because in ideal world we should concatenate 2 available neighbors on step 6.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is pretty much exactly the same as roguelike dungeon map generation. There are a ton of approaches to this with different looks.

I would suggest the BSP tree approach from here ( the steps are simple ): 
http://www.futuregadgetlab.com/proceduraldungeon/

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the computation and start with some limitation of the rotation then you can use a kd-tree. A good example is the jquery masonry plugin or the jquery treemap algorithm. The idea is to position a rectangle somewhere and separate the x points to the left and the y points to the right of the tree.

Comment: It's actually restricted to 90 degree rotation

Comment: Yes, I mean 90 degree rotation. I'm not sure why I wrote 45 degree.